# Should I ask this as 3 separate questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, asking-questions

I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/800027/80965) yesterday, but I started wondering since long questions are not very popular, if I should ask it as 3 different questions or leave it as it is now.

Comment: Split up the questions. I, and I suspect many others, tend to browse math stackexchange with a short attention span--that is, unless I get hooked by an interesting problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few points.

1. Separate, *related* questions can certainly be asked in the same question, if you so desire.  So there's not necessarily anything wrong with the way you did it.
2. It's true that long questions are not always accepted as well as concise questions.  Therefore, no one will blame you if you decide to split up the three questions.  Alternatively, you can set up a **bounty** to give your question more attention, and if you do it will very likely get a good response.
3. If you do ask related questions separately, **make sure you link to the older questions in the later questions.**

I also agree with Asaf's [comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13755/should-i-ask-this-as-3-separate-questions/13845?noredirect=1#comment54700_13845) below: unless the questions are strongly related (i.e. in order to understand the later questions you need to have read the earlier questions) ask them separately.

Comment: The first one should be *quite* related, not just related. One should also not throw in too many questions into the same thread. For example, a list of seven sets with the sole question of "what is their cardinality" (even if all sets have the same cardinality) is certainly not a good fit for this site. Asking two questions which are natural extensions of one another, and are strongly of the same block of wood, that *might* be acceptable, but depends on the situation.

Comment: A person with a long list of questions can hopefully solve the remaining questions themselves after seeing some of them being solved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll keep that in mind. By now I've already _solve_ the question, except for one part that has been bothering me a lot. I've been thinking in posting an answer, and hope someone will correct/extend it.